# how do I alter a link in the my account navigation column in magento?

Tags: magento

im trying to alter the navigation links in the my account section of my magento site currently they look like this:

[image]

I turned on debug template paths so I can locate where it came from but it just sent me to navigation.phtml, which was just some php code the echos the links in a list form see below.

```
<div class="block block-account">
<div class="block-title">
    <strong><span><?php echo $this->__('My Account'); ?></span></strong>
</div>
<div class="block-content">
    <ul>
        <?php $_links = $this->getLinks(); ?>
        <?php $_index = 1; ?>
        <?php $_count = count($_links); ?>
        <?php foreach ($_links as $_link): ?>
            <?php $_last = ($_index++ >= $_count); ?>
            <?php if ($this->isActive($_link)): ?>
                <li class="current<?php echo ($_last ? ' last' : '') ?>"><strong><?php echo $_link->getLabel() ?></strong></li>
            <?php else: ?>
                <li<?php echo ($_last ? ' class="last"' : '') ?>><a href="<?php echo $_link->getUrl() ?>"><?php echo $_link->getLabel() ?></a></li>
            <?php endif; ?>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
</div>
```

My goal is simple to rename "My Wishlist" to "My Sample Request" any ideas on how to achieve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If renaming is only the issue than it is very simple.
You just edit the name in the "app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/wishlist.xml".
you will search for below code.

```
 <customer_account>
        <!-- Mage_Wishlist -->
        <reference name="customer_account_navigation">
            <action method="addLink" translate="label" module="wishlist" ifconfig="wishlist/general/active"><name>wishlist</name><path>wishlist/</path><label>My Wishlist</label></action>
        </reference>
    </customer_account>
```

change the label "My Wishlist" to "My Sample Request".

This will work.But its not the best way to achieve this.First Override the "wishlist.xml" to your theme and then only make a change.

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

you dont need to do this from xml file , just open the

> `app/locale/en_US/Mage_XmlConnect.csv

and around line 601 you wil see a `"My Wishlist","My Wishlist"`
you can change from there. if you will change in xml file than in multilangual site it will same for all languages. So change from translate file.

thanks

Comment: make sure just change the text like this "My Wishlist","My Sample Request"

Answer (score -1):

`$this->getLinks()` is heart of that template. It retrieves all links as an array and then loop through it and display each item. So the array returned by that code is actually constituted by another method `addLink()`. It normally use in layout files. My guess is, you need to alter that name in layout file.

File : `app\design\frontend\<package>\<theme>\layout\customer.xml`

You can see many code like this

```
<action method="addLink" translate="label" module="customer">
     <name>account</name>
     <path>customer/account/</path>
     <label>Account Dashboard</label>
</action>
```

Here `label` is the part that you need to change.

So check for this code in `customer.xml` file. Find the code that generate "Wisthlist" link. Then change the label part according to your need

Comment: prove my answer is wrong. I have pointed out how those links appears there through my answer. There is no problem with down voting. But make sure what i have made wrong, so that I can improve